# libgdx y axis rotation (card flip)

Tags: android, libgdx

I am a complete new user to libgdx and am looking to use it to write a simple card game.

I want to be able to flip my cards over to reveal them, in the same way as this example from Google shows.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

However, my game is only 2D so i can't find a command that will do this. I've found a suggestion on stack overflow which might work, but i don't think it will give a sense of perspective/depth when the card is turned.

[Libgdx rotate an actor on its Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436674/libgdx-rotate-an-actor-on-its-y-axis)

Am i going to have to somehow use a 3D library for this part of the game? It seems a bit overkill. Or is it possible to combine some part of the android SDK animation code within a libgdx game?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to combine parts of android sdk code within a libgdx game, but you would lose platform independence (you can't test it on desktop except emulator).

---

Using a 3D library is not an overkill at all and is really easy to implement in libgdx.

Have a look at [Decal](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Decals)s. 2D actors in a 3D world. I suppose that is exactly what you need.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, yes Decals might be the way to go. I've come across them in research, except I've always dismissed them as being too much 3D. I'm going to crack on with the game itself rather than worrying about the flip animation, then I'll come back and look at this later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decrement the sprite's size to zero and move it to the right at 1/2 of the speed it is shrinking. When the card has disappeared, change the sprite and do the same process backwards.